# How does using DynamicResource 'magically' convert a brush to a color?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, dynamicresource

I have defined some brush resources in terms of system colors like the following:

```
<SolidColorBrush 
   x:Key="brushKey1" 
   Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlColor}" 
   />
```

(This is done because some third-party code expects to find `brushKey1` defined).

But I noticed that the following also compiles and appears to work:

```
<SolidColorBrush 
   x:Key="brushKey1" 
   Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}}" 
   />
```

The first one uses a COLOR object, but the second uses a BRUSH.

Why does this work? Is `DynamicResource` automatically figuring out how to do some sort of cast or conversion?

Note that this does not work:

```
<SolidColorBrush 
   x:Key="brushKey1" 
   Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}" 
   />
```

This line will compile but throws a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic or conversion. Take a look to the `Resources`, there must be an entry with a `SystemColors.ControlBrush` object as key.

So in case

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushKey1"  Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}}"/>
```

you get "value" of an entry from `ResourceDictionary`.

in another case

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushKey1"  Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}"/>
```

you try to assign the object, which being used as "key" in `ResourceDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Compiles? Yes. Your `brushKey1` references a resource with an `x:Key` of `{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}` using the [`DynamicResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dynamicresource-markup-extension) markup extension. You could set the key to anything. It would still compile.

Works? No, not unless you have defined a `Color` resource with an `x:Key` of `{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}`:

```
<Color x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}">Red</Color>
```